# Not able to start animation from didselectrowatindexpath in first tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am animating a view over table view when user taps a cell. Although my DidSeclectRowAtIndexPath is getting called when I tap the cell first time but the animation does not take place. On the second tap the animation block gets triggered.
What may be causing this issue?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.ChosenSubCategory=[self.SubCategoryListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self getUserSpecificLevelDetails];
   // [self ShowLevelPickerView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
             [self.ChooseLevelView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the threading issue.

Please try the below solution. Hope it works.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 

*)indexPath
{
    self.ChosenSubCategory=[self.SubCategoryListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self getUserSpecificLevelDetails];
   // [self ShowLevelPickerView];

    [self performSelector:@selector(performOperation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


- (void)performOperation
{
      [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
             [self.ChooseLevelView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }];`
}
```